# How can I create an instance of my Iterator private class in `main()`

Tags: java

What's the syntax for creating an instance of the Iterator private class in `main()`?

I have this:

```
public class OuterClass implements Iterable<Integer{

   .....
   public Iterator<Integer> iterator(){
       return new MyIterator();
   }

   private MyIterator implements Iterator<Integer>{
      .....
   }

}
```

Inside the `main()` method, I'm trying to do something like 
`MyClass.MyIterator<String> iter = object.iterator();`
but it's not working.

Comment: What is `object`? An instance of OuterClass ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to access the private implementation of the `Iterator` interface from the outside.

Just use the interface type :

```
 Iterator<Integer> iter = object.iterator();
```

If for some reason you must access the specific `MyClass.MyIterator` implementing class, don't declare it as `private`.

Comment: Either this is simply make MyIterator public, but odds are you have it private for a reason, so this is probably the best way about it.